# Submit button clearing out form, and not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, html, validation, form-submit

I'm trying to create a fun little registration sheet to practice my validation. When I hit the submit button I have two issues. The first issue is my form keeps clearing every input field the moment I hit submit. I tried to use have my onclick = return false but this did nothing. The next issue I'm having is when I hit submit nothing happens at all. I'm not sure where I have messed up but if someone could point it out to me.

```js
<!-- create a function to validate and pass information along -->
    function Validation() {
    
    <!-- declare variables -->
        var ifErrors = false;
        
        <!-- create the array to display error messages when cycled through -->
        var ErrorMessage = new Array();
        
        var myUserName = document.getElementById("txtUsername").value;
        var myPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
        var myFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
        var myLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
        var myDateOfBirth = document.getElementById("txtDateOfBirth").value;
        var myEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
        var myPhoneNumber = document.getElementById("txtPhoneNumber").value;
        var LettersOnly = /^[a-z]+$/;
        var DateOfBirthValidate = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
        var Dates = new Date();
        var DateSupplied = document.getElementById("txtDateOfBirth").value;
        var PhoneNumberValidate = /^\([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        
        
        <!-- Begin validation -->
        
        //validate for username being blank
        if (myUserName = "")
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Username is required');
            }
        
        //validate for username not being 8 or more characters
        if(myUserName.length < 8)
                {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Username must be 8 or more characters');
                }
        
        //validate for password being blank 
        if (myPassword == "")
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Password is required');
            }
        
        //validate for password not being 8 or more characters
        if (myPassword.length < 8)
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Password must be 8 or more characters');
            }
        
        //validate for first name being blank
        if (myFirstName == "")
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('First name can not be blank');
            }
        
        //validate for last name being blank
        if (myLastName == "")
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Last name can not be blank');
            }   
            
        //validate for date of birth being blank
        if (myDateOfBirth == "")
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Last name can not be blank');
            }   
        
        //validate for date of birth not being formatted like (MM/DD/YYYY)
        if (document.getElementById("txtDateOfBirth").value.length > 1)
            {
                if (! (txtDateOfBirth,valueOf().match(DateOfBirthValidate)));
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('not a valid date of birth');
            }
            }
            
        //create a variable to hold date, and see if it's greater than the current date
        DateSupplied = new Date(DateSupplied);
        if (DateSupplied > Dates)  
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Date supplied can not be greater than the current date');
            }
        
        
        //va;idate for phone number
        if (document.getElementById("txtPhoneNumber").value.length > 1)
            {
                if (! (txtPhoneNumber.valueOf().match(PhoneNumberValidate)))
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                ErrorMessage.push('Phone number is not valid');
            }
            }
        
        //successful validation
        if (ifErrors == false)
            {
                ifErrors = true;
                alert('Your registration has been processed');
                //document.getElementById("RegisterForm").reset();
            }
        
        //Display list of messages in list 
        var DisplayMessage = "";
        ErrorMessage.forEach(function (message) 
            {
                DisplayMessage += "<li>" + message + "</li>";
            }
            );
            
        document.getElementById("Errors").innerHTML = DisplayMessage;
                    
}
```

```html
<body>

        
        <h3>Registration</h3>
<div>
        <ul id="Errors"> </ul>
        

</div>
        
        <br/>
        
        <form ="RegisterForm">
        <label id="lblUsername">Username:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblPassword">Password:</label>
        
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblFirstName">First Name:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblLastName">Last Name:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtLastName" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblDateOfBirth">Date of Birth:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtDateOfBirth" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblEmail">Email:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" />
        <br/>
        
        <label id="lblPhoneNumber">Email:</label>
        
        <input type="text" id="txtPhoneNumber" />    
        <br/>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Validation(); return false;" />
        <input type="reset" value="reset Form" />
        
        </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`return false;` does not stop the form from being submitted.

In order to achieve this behavior, you have to call `.preventDefault()` on the `click` event of the `<input>`, or on the `submit` event of the `<form>`. Example:

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" onclick="someFn(event)">
</form>
<script>
  function someFn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('form not submitted...');
  }
</script>
```

To prevent all submit events in one go (regardless of which form element initiated it) you can call `.preventDefault()` on the form's `onsubmit` handler parameter (which is the `submit` event):

```html
<form onsubmit="someFn(event)">
  <input type="submit">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  function someFn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('form not submitted...');
  }
</script>
```

As a side-note, the submit input ***does not*** clear out your form. It sends it.
Because you haven't specified an `action` attribute on your `<form>` element, the submission is sent to the current URL.
Which, in practice, reloads the page.
Which, in practice renders a brand new instance of the form, obviously empty.

This is also the reason why *"nothing happens at all"*. The default browser behavior when *submitting a form* is to actually load the `<form>`'s `action` URL (whether it's explicitly specified or not). You're navigating to that URL, along with the form's values. Which means you're not allowing the browser to finish running the code in `Validation();`. To wait around and see the results of `Validation` function, you have to prevent the default form submission behavior.

---

Docs:

- `<form>`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), [HTML (Living Standard)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element)
- `<input type="submit">`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit), [HTML (Living Standard)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#submit-button-state-(type%3Dsubmit))
- `Event.preventDefault()`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), [DOM (Living Standard)](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault)